# Word for someone who focuses on the smaller details of a bigger problem

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not sure if the title correctly describes what I'm looking for.

For example, there is a debate about the existence of something, and one party focuses on the small unexplained details in their opponents' argument and do not address the gaping holes in theirs.

Comment: That sounds like a "clever negotiator".

Comment: Your question calls to mind the saying that Jesus popularized in his Sermon on the Mount in the story commonly known as [*The mote and the beam*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mote_and_the_Beam).

Comment: Nitpicker, if he is your boss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single word, I suggest ***myopic***:

> **Myopic** is an adjective meaning shortsighted in every sense. Whether you need glasses or a new attitude, if you can't see the forest for the trees, you're *myopic*.
>   <sub>[Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/myopic)</sub>

However, for the example you provided, I would describe the person as a ***lawyer***.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a single word, but the expression **can't see the wood for the trees** refers to exactly this situation ([reference](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/can%27t+see+the+wood+for+the+trees)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That expression does fit nicely.

Comment: In the US it's generally "can't see the forest for the trees".

Answer (score 2):

When the problem consists of something no-one wants to acknowledge or talk about, it is very often referred to as 'the elephant in the room'.

In passing, it's worth noting that you generally can't get many elephants into a room, but there's usually quite a lot of room inside an elephant.