# Word for focusing on the details to the detriment of the whole?

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a specific word I'm looking for and I even remember it being from Philip Roth's novel 'American Pastoral'. I just can't think of what the actual word is, but its meaning is to focus on the specifics of something to the detriment of the whole.

Comment: There's also [Word for someone who focuses on the smaller details of a bigger problem](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251919/word-for-someone-who-focuses-on-the-smaller-details-of-a-bigger-problem)

Comment: You may like to look at this definition of *parochial* and its synonyms --> https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=parochial+definition&ie=&oe=

Comment: Well, there's the idiom "can't see the forest for the trees", and there's the word "myopic".